# Invalid or corrupt jarfile android.jar issue

Tags: eclipse, cordova, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to build and run an android project using the **[phonegap](http://phonegap.com/start/#android)** framework.

I have configured the IDE and followed the steps described in an official tutorial (see link above).
The problem is that I never had a chance to build the project since it contains errors. The major one is (see screenshots):

```
Archive for required library: 'C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-8/android.jar' in project 'xxx' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

[image: Eclipse IDE 'Problems' tab]

Also, I have tried to manually run the aforementioned **android.jar** but got the same error:

[image: JVM launcher error]

The problem keeps reproducing through several SDK versions: r14, r15.

BTW, I experience no troubles building a project using other android versions, e.g., 2.3.

Would someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Android package manager to remove and then re-download the Android 2.2 SDK as something is corrupt with that package.

Comment: Do you mean the 'Android SDK Manager' in Eclipse?

Comment: Yup, this resolved an issue with broken jar. But there are errors left (as on the screenshot, except for the 1st - fixed). Apparently, there are some problems with `main.xml`...

Comment: Glad that worked for you. After that I'd close and re-open eclipse. Turn off build auto, run a clean, turn on build auto to see if the other errors go away. It looks like your R file is not being generated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that Eclipse had some cached and not reinitialized items... all resolved! Take care!